# Creating data frame by using extracted coefficients from a list

Tags: r, list, extract, coefficients

I run almost 40 logistic regression by using the same set of independent variables, but 40 different dependent variables. I would like to extract coefficients from 40 regression lines, and create a data frame to plot dot plot. I think it is better to visualise it rather than putting all regression lines in the same table.

I could not figure out how to extract the effect of an independent variable (same type of coefficients from each equations)

Appreciated if you can help me out!

Here is an reproducible example.

```
set.seed(10) 
y <- matrix(rnorm(10000 * 14), ncol = 14) 
x <- matrix(rnorm(10000 * 2), ncol = 2) 
res <- lapply(1:14, function(i) lm(y[, i] ~ x))
```

Comment: `res <- apply(y, 2, function(z) lm(z~x))` will be a little more efficient, since `apply` was specifically designed for column-wise operations.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `do.call` and `rbind` on your list `res`

```
> do.call(rbind, lapply(res, function(x) coef(x)))
        (Intercept)            x1            x2
 [1,]  1.440115e-03 -0.0198232209 -0.0005720764
 [2,] -2.227644e-02 -0.0134155339 -0.0092420757
 [3,]  3.535811e-03 -0.0284229117  0.0140198529
 [4,] -2.031279e-02  0.0032004789 -0.0036719760
 [5,] -1.127532e-02 -0.0004463859 -0.0116754425
 [6,] -1.369851e-02  0.0174797415  0.0112791379
```

It's a matrix, use `data.frame` to get a `data.frame`